# Passing ArrayList to PHP using Android Asynchronous Http Client Issue

Tags: java, php, android, arraylist

Im trying to send ArrayList to PHP ($_POST) and use it as an array.
I use Android Asynchronous Http Client http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

My code

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add("1");
array.add("2");
array.add("3");
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("descr_array", array );
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post(StaticValues.SERVER_PAGE, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() { ... }
```

In PHP

```
$descrarray[] = $_POST['descr_array'];
```

shows only one item, as a string.

```
$result = print_r($_POST);
print(json_encode($result));
```

Debugging code shows

> Array ( [descr_array] => 1 )

There is only one string, how can I solve it?

Comment: use json to get the values in php.

Comment: Name your field `descr_array[]` instead of `desc_array`. The extra `[]` is a signal to PHP to treat multiple of the same input name as an array, rather than only using the last value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get all values write:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("descr_array_1", array.get(0) );
params.put("descr_array_2", array.get(1) );
params.put("descr_array_2", array.get(2) );
```

But I prefer you to use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert Array to String and use one pair only:

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String out = gson.toJson(array);
params.put("descr_array", out );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```java
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

for (String val : array) {
    params.add("descr_array[]", val);
}
```

It doesn't require you to add extra Headers or import other libraries and works for both `JSON` and `XML`.

---

*The important thing to note here is the use of `add` instead of `put`. [See the difference between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27649251/difference-between-requestparams-add-and-put-in-androidasynchttp/27649265#27649265).*

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
Map<String, String> aMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
aMap.put("f_name" ,"");
aMap.put("l_name" ,"");
aMap.put("email" ,edtEmail.getText().toString());
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("user",aMap);

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post(url, params, n.....
```