# Difference between RequestParams add() and put() in AndroidAsyncHttp

Tags: android, android-async-http

While using the `android-async-http` library I stumbled upon `params.add()`.

I've been using `params.put()` for a while and it seems better than `add()` since it allows data types other than *String* (like *int*, *long*, *object*, *file*) while `add()` does not.

```java
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

// So how is this
params.add("param_a", "abc");

// different from this
params.put("param_a", "abc");

// and which one should I use?
```

Comment: Use `add()` for Arrays and `put()` for everything else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The major difference between the two** (other than `add()`'s String-only support) is that `put()` overwrites the previous presence of `param` with an existing key while `add()` does not.

For example:

```java
params.put("etc", "etc");
params.put("key", "abc");
params.put("key", "xyz");

// Params: etc=etc&key=xyz
```

While add creates two `params` with the same key:

```java
params.add("etc", "etc");
params.add("key", "abc");
params.add("key", "xyz");

// Params: etc=etc&key=abc&key=xyz
```

---

**But what is the importance of doing this?**

In the above example, the web-server would only read the last value of `key` i.e. `xyz` and not `abc` but this is [useful when **POST**ing arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27648988/1533054):

```java
params.add("key[]", "a");
params.add("key[]", "b");
params.add("key[]", "c");

// Params: key[]=a&key[]=b&key[]=c
// The server will read it as: "key" => ["a", "b", "c"]
```